# Expected value for total variation distance of random finite probability distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $P_n$ and $Q_n$ be two random finite probability distribution functions of $n$ elements. By random, I mean they are generated in the following manner

$1)$ Set $P^{'}_n=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n,\}$ where $a_i$ is picked uniformly from $[0,1]$

$2)$ Define $\chi=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$

$3)$ Set $P_n=\frac{P^{'}_n}{\chi}=\left\{\frac{a_1}{\chi},\frac{a_2}{\chi},...,\frac{a_n}{\chi}\right\}$

The total variation distance of $P_n$ and $Q_n$ is defined as

$$\delta(P_n,Q_n)= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n|P_n(i)-Q_n(i)|$$

My question is: Can we prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\delta(P_n,Q_n)\in \left(\frac{1}{3}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon\right)\right)=1$$

That is, does the probability that $\delta(P_n,Q_n)$ is near $\frac{1}{3}$ go to $1$ as $n$ gets large? Numerical evidence would support that this is true. After checking the total variation distance for $10^4$ random PDFs with $n=2^9$ elements each, I get a histogram that looks like

[[image: <span class=]$2^9$ elements">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aImSJ.png)

For $n=2^{12}$ elements I get

[[image: <span class=]$2^{12}$ elements">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGFXm.png)

As you can see, they both are symmetrical around $\frac{1}{3}$. Additionally, the first graph seems to go from $.30$ to $.36$ while the second graph goes from $.32$ to $.345$. This suggests that if $n$ goes to infinity the graphs should collapse around $\frac{1}{3}$. Of course, if this is difficult to prove, I would also be interested in proving that the expected value converges to $\frac{1}{3}$ as $n$ gets large (it actually is less than $\frac{1}{3}$ in both these graphs but it converges very rapidly so I felt comfortable saying it was $\frac{1}{3}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint and a line of attack.

Note that your formula for $\delta$ makes sense for arbitrary vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, not just probability vectors.

Suppose you generate random vectors $x_N=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)/(n/2), y_N=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)/(n/2)$ by picking the coordinates i.i.d. with $a_i, b_i\sim U[0,1]$. Then by the SLLN, $\delta(x_n,y_n)\to 1/3$ almost surely, as $n\to\infty$.  (You should check this last assertion as homework.)  Of course the $x_n$ and $y_n$ vectors are not probability vectors, because the sums of their coordinates are not exactly $1$ but only close to $1$.  By the SLNN, these sums converge to $1$ with probability $1$, so they are in a sense getting closer to probability vectors.

So the plan is, to use the same $a_i$ etc to generate your $P_n$ vectors and my $x_n$ vectors, and find a probability bound on $\delta(P_n,x_n)$ and so on the difference between $\delta(P_n,Q_n)-\delta(x_n,y_n)$.

Comment: Very nice hint. I spent way too long trying to look for a closed form for it and this works extremely well. Just a note but the random vectors sums go to $1/2$ not $1$. Its fine though because as I went through the analysis I was missing a factor of $2$ and thats where it was.